# Creating many sorted data frames from a single larger frame

Tags: r

Current dilemma:  I have a massive data frame that I am trying to break down into smaller files based on a partial string match in the column.  I have made a script that works great for this:

```
df <- read.csv("file.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
newdf <- select(df, matches('threshold1',))
write.csv(newdf,"threshold1.file.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

The problem is that I have hundreds of thresholds to break apart into separate files.  There must be a way I can loop this script to create all the files for me rather than manually editing the script to say threshold2, threshold3, etc.

Comment: `for (i in 1:N) {m = paste0('threshold',i); newdf = select(df, matches(m,)); write.csv(newdf, paste0(m, ".file.csv"), row.names = FALSE)}`

Comment: where N = what exactly?

Comment: the number of thresholds - you'll have to get this number yourself as you did not provide a full example

Comment: Whoa that worked perfectly!  So rad.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to solve it with lapply.

```
# Functions that splits and saves the data.frame
split_df <-  function(threshold, df){
  newdf <- select(df, matches(threshold,))
  write.csv(newdf,
            paste(".file.csv", sep = ""), row.names = FALSE)
  return(threshold)
}

df <- read.csv("file.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

# Number for thresholds
N <- 100
threshold_l <- paste("threshold", 1:N, sep = "")

lapply(threshold_l, split_df, df = df)
```